# How to Multiply values like math

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I do multiplication in hand form?

by hand form I mean:
Take two numbers as input, 
then output in a text box,
the multiplication steps as it would be done by a school student.

so for the inputs 819 and 1358 I wish to output:

```
                    8 1 9
                  1 3 5 8    
              x_____________
                8 1 9 0 0 0
                5 4 5 7 0 0
                  1 0 9 5 0 
                  1 4 5 5 2 
            +__________________     
               1 4 7 0 2 0 2
```

I can of-course get the final answer though the multiplication operation: `(a*b)` 
but that will not let me display the steps.

Comment: You just answered your own question. Use long a = 819, b = 1358, c;  c = a*b;

Comment: but i want to show plus values in any richtextbox or textbox

Comment: Have you tried google.com for answers?

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s2p13.html

Comment: yes but i can't find thats y i post my question :P

Comment: It is a cute problem -- is it homework? (no rule against homework). It is not too broad in my mind.

It would be much better if you showed some sample code.
(Hint: it may be easyer to treat the numbers as a string and parse it character by character from the back, that or have an array of bytes one for each character, and clip each value if it goes over 10. Think about how you would do this multiplication on paper)

Comment: @WernervandenHeever i have 2 numbers

Comment: @user3796280 : I have made significant edits to highlight what I believe your actual question to be.
It is (as I said before) kinda cute.
You should check my edits and see if that is what you mean to say.
Your should also add some sample code.
Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Easiest thing I can think is to split the numbers into an integer array each holding one digit. Example a = 123 and b = 456 split the integer 123 into an array a[] { 1,2,3 } and same with integer b.  Then step through them in reverse of the array to get the steps. So take a[2] * b[2]. That will get you step one. Which will give you 18. Then split the 1 and 8 into an int array. To display in the separate columns. Interesting question by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you require.

Then modify like following

```
        List<double> lst = new List<double>();
        string strInput2 = txtInput2.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < strInput2.Length; i++)
        {
            double dbl = Convert.ToDouble(txtInput1.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(strInput2[strInput2.Length - (i + 1)].ToString());
            string zeros = new String('0', i);
            lst.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dbl + zeros));

            //richTextBoxResult.Text += lst[i] + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        for (int i = lst.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            richTextBoxResult.Text += lst[i] + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        richTextBoxResult.Text += "________________" + Environment.NewLine;

        richTextBoxResult.Text += lst.Sum();
```

Comment: thx for this but i want revers first value shown like my eg.